# ValueError: shapes (50,6) and (50,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 50 (dim 0)

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, statsmodels

I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: shapes (50,6) and (50,6) not aligned:  6 (dim 1) != 50 (dim 0)".
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to "align" these matrices? I am using Python 3.5.1.

```py
real_x = data.iloc[:,0:4].values
real_y= data.iloc[:,4].values

le = LabelEncoder()
real_x[:,3] = le.fit_transform(real_x[:,3])
oneHE = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[3])#categorical features col 3
real_x = oneHE.fit_transform(real_x).toarray()


real_x = real_x[:,1:]

training_x,test_x,training_y,test_y = train_test_split(real_x,real_y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)


MLR = LinearRegression()
MLR.fit(training_x,training_y)

Pred_y = MLR.predict(test_x)
real_x = np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1)).astype(int),values=real_x, axis=1)

x_opt= real_x[:,[0,1,2,3,4]]
reg_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=real_x, exog=x_opt).fit()
m  = reg_OLS.summary()

real_x.shape
(50, 6)
x_opt.shape
(50, 5)
```

i tried reshaping  them but again it shows an error

```
x_opt.reshape(50,6)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 250 into shape (50,6)
```

here is the full error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-02d59637cd4f> in <module>()
----> 1 m  = reg_OLS.summary()

ValueError: shapes (50,6) and (50,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 50 (dim 0)
```

Comment: Which matrices? *Where exactly* does the error pop up? This is useful info for possible respondents - storytelling details can be safely omitted. Please post the full error trace.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

OLS is only for univariate dependent variable (`endog`), your endog is multivariate. 
statsmodels has currently no proper support for multivariate LS versions.

Several multivariate LS models are implemented in the `linearmodels` package.
https://pypi.org/project/linearmodels/

OLS can estimate the `params` for multivariate endog, but other results statistics are not available. That's why it raises in summary and not if model creation or fit.

Comment: i am learning it from Youtube the instructor is able to execute this code

Comment: No idea what the instructor is doing, maybe she/he has a 1-dim endog. In any case, it does not work with statsmodels OLS.